# Make two series of async calls with a delay in between

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I need to make a series of AJAX calls (to different URLs), then only after *all* of them are done make another series of calls. My code so far:

```
(function (delay) {
    var toDo = 10, // for example
    curr = 0;
    process = setInterval(function() {
        // do a call
        // blahblahblah
        // then:
        if(curr === toDo) {
            clearInterval(process);
        } else {
            curr++;
        }
    }, delay);
})(2000);
// repeat for the 2nd series, but this code will execute immediately since they are async
```

The reason I'm using this format instead of a simple `for` loop is because I need to pause between each call. I can't launch the 2nd series until after the 1st series is all finished, since that's where I get the URLs for the 2nd series from; so I can't just shove all my calls into the same self-calling function. I need for the 2nd series to execute *only* after the 1st series is done.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just regular `XMLHttpRequest` for the AJAX?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS, but I can use either jQuery or XHR if needed.

Comment: So you are using $http/$resource?

Comment: Yeah, `$http.get(someurl, ...`.

Comment: OK, I'm just going to give you pseudo-code for this and you can convert that to Angular.js however you want.

Comment: That's fine, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have the code for your second series all set up and easily available and that all you need help with is making sure the second series is only called after the first series is all done. With that assumption, here's some pseudocode for what you need to do:

```
(function (delay) {
    var toDo = 10, // for example
    curr = 0,
    numDone = 0; //This is the number of requests we've finished and gotten a response for.
    process = setInterval(function() {
        // Setup a call.
        [...]
        // Make some callback that _at the end, increments numDone_.
        [...]
        // Send the call.
        [...]
        // Then:
        if(curr === toDo) {
            clearInterval(process);

            //Now, here's where we check if we're done with all of these requests:
            (function(delay2) {
                 //Every so often, check if we're done by seeing if numDone equals toDo:
                 var checkDone = setInterval(function() {
                     if (numDone === toDo) {
                         //Thus, stop checking if we're done:
                         clearInterval(checkDone);
                         //Finally, start the second series of calls:
                         [...]
                     }
                 }, delay2);
            })(1000);
            //We're checking every second as passed in above, but you can change this however you want.
        } else {
            curr++;
        }
    }, delay);
})(2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming jQuery, you should be able to do this using promises:

```
$.when( // first set
    $.ajax({}),
    $.ajax({})
).then(function(){ // second set
    $.ajax({});
    $.ajax({});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I'm using this format instead of a simple for loop is
>   because I need to pause between each call. I can't launch the 2nd
>   series until after the 1st series is all finished, since that's where
>   I get the URLs for the 2nd series from; so I can't just shove all my
>   calls into the same self-calling function. I need for the 2nd series
>   to execute only after the 1st series is done.

Delay not appear necessary to return expected results ? Try utilizing `Promise.all()`

```
var requests = [function doAsyncStuff1() {}, function doAsyncStuff2() {}];

var res = Promise.all(requests.map(function(request) {
  return request()
}));

res.then(function success(data) {
  // do stuff with response from `doAsyncStuff1` , `doAsyncStuff2`
}, function error(err) {
  // log errors , if any
  console.log(err)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

$http methods return a promise. You can use the `then` callbacks to call the next ajax request. This uses the `$q` service which is angular's promise service, so make sure to inject it into your controller/factory/directive.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MainCtrl",["$scope","$q","$http",function($scope,$q,$http){
  $scope.log = [];

  //Start the requests for the next set of urls
  function nextSet(urls){
     var deferreds = urls.map(function(url){
         $scope.log.push("Starting url: "+url);
         return $http.get(url);
     });

     //$q.all takes an array of deferreds and will be fulfilled when 
     //all of them resolve.
     return $q.all(deferreds);
  }

  var urlSets = [ 
     [ "https://cors-test.appspot.com/test?1",
       "https://cors-test.appspot.com/test?2" ], 
     [ "https://cors-test.appspot.com/test?3",
       "https://cors-test.appspot.com/test?4",
       "https://cors-test.appspot.com/test?5"] ];
  var dataSets = [];
    
  //The main deferred
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  //Loop through the sets, chaining 'then'
  //This will end up basically making up a queue
  //Each chained 'then' callback will be called after
  //each set of requests have resolved
  var promise = urlSets.reduce(function(promise,urlSet){

     //return promise so it can be used in the next iteration
     return promise
       
       //Chain the nextSet call, binding the urlSet to the call
       .then(nextSet.bind(null,urlSet))
       
       //Just chaining an extra callback to show previous call was done
       //Could use it to do special processing for each set
       //after they have been fetched
       .then(function(dataSet){
         $scope.log.push("Set Finished: "+urlSet.join(","));
         dataSets.push(dataSet);
         return dataSets;
       });

  },deferred.promise);

  //The final 'then' callback, called when all sets have been resolved
  promise.then(function(dataSets){
    //All done
    $scope.log.push("All done");
    
    //all the data fetched from urls will be in dataSets
    //it will be an array of the sets with each index matching to 
    //to the indexes of the urlSets. so dataSets[0] will hold the array of             
    //data fetched from urlSets[0] and so on
    console.log(dataSets);
  });
  
  //Start the process
  deferred.resolve();      
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="line in log">
      {{line}}
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This code assumes all the urls will resolve. If any of the requests fail, the rest will not be processed. If you need to rest of the requests to be processed even if any of the others fail you will need to add in appropriate code to deal with that situation.

[Angular's $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)